# Shouldn't pixel value 20930 of a 16-bit PNG be a shade of grey?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to create a 16-bit PNG and the largest pixel value is:

```
depth_array = np.array(depth_img, dtype=np.float32)
depth_array[np.isnan(depth_array)] = 0
depth_array *= 5000
depth_array = depth_array.astype(np.uint16)
print(np.max(depth_array)) # 20930
```

However, the image I get contains a lot of whites:

[image]

Isn't 20930 meant to be grey as 20930 is closer to 0 (black) than to 65535 (white)?

Comment: I think you're incorrectly converting to 16-bit. Try `depth_img = depth_img.astype(np.uint16)` then `depth_img *= 256`

Comment: @nathancy The original depth image contains pixel values up to 10. I'm actually trying to scale them up by 5000 and preserve as much precision as possible.

Comment: Fixed. I just had to convert it to uint16. Anyone know why it shows white if the image was in float32?

Comment: What tool are you using to view the image?

Comment: @yellow01 Well, the one above is just the browser. I've used Ubuntu's image viewer to view it too.

Comment: how did you save the image? Browsers typically dont use floating point images. If you use opencv imwrite or imshow, they assume float pixels to be 0 = pure black and 1 = pure white and scale accordingly if written to 8 bit or 16 bit output or display.

Comment: `depth_image` is a `numpy` array so you can't view it in image viewer. i.e. there is probably more going on in your code that you are not showing us. Can you provide the part of your code where you save the image?

Comment: @yellow01 I indeed saved it using `cv2.imwrite`, as @Micka rightly pointed out.

Comment: @Micka Does that mean all pixel values >= 1 would be scaled to 1? That is, 1 or 20930 would be appear white.

Comment: yes, everything >=1 will be mapped to the maximum value (e.g. 255 for 8 bit)